# how to extract attributes of an element from an XML using xslt and display in different style

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, tridion

I am new to XSLT. I am working transforming an XML file from one format to another format.
I also want to extract values from an element and display the them in bold format.

Sample source XML:

```
 <Content xmlns="uuid:4522eb85">
      <first xmlns="uuid:4522eb85">Hello World. This is first field</first>
      <second author="XYZ">Hi iam second field</second>
 </Content>
```

Output format required:

```
  <root>
     <aaa>Hello World. This is first field</aaa>
     <bbb><author>**XYZ**</author>Hi iam second field</bbb>
  <root>
```

I am unable to extract attributes from a tag and display with style(say bold).

Please help.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is that a SDL Tridion schema? Where does the author attribute get added? I thought field data is saved as child nodes rather than in any attributes.

Comment: You should check out the XSLT tutorial at W3Schools.com - http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/default.asp. I consider myself reasonably competent as XSLT now, although it's not a skill I practice regularly. I find the information on that site to be very useful whenever I need to refresh my memory on a particular approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This XSLT outputs exactly what you ask for.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:c="uuid:4522eb85" exclude-result-prefixes="c">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/c:Content">
        <root>
            <aaa><xsl:value-of select="c:first"/></aaa>
            <bbb><author>**<xsl:value-of select="c:second/@author" />**</author><xsl:value-of select="c:second" /></bbb>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But as Jeremy suggests, you may want to consider first taking an (online) XSLT training if you want to get much further.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display the text with style then you have to display the content in html. You should use XSLT to get the info from XML and create a HTML output with you required style

Comment: @Raghuram..Is it not possible to diaplay in XMl itself by adding some extensions. Because my final output needs to be in xml only.

Comment: You cant...as XML is a meta language and it specify a set of rules on representing data. For presenting the data you have to have it in HTML or other formats...

Comment: _XML schema_ would be the "rules representing data" definition, @Raghuram. The output, especially with Tridion, can be _any_ text-based format, including XML (or XSD if somehow needed). You're right that "bold" style makes sense in terms of web pages, but the question is still valid.